# Using Vlookup In VBA With Filter Conditions

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

What I am trying to accomplish here is

> 1) Is to iterate the values in column O and for the ones that are not null - filter the worksheet titled DATA to only show values where Column B = X and use VLOOKUP() to return the lookup values to the corresponding row in Column P
>   
> 2) If column O is null then filter the sheet titled DATA to only show values where Column B <> X and use VLOOKUP() to return the lookup values to the corresponding row in Column P.

I attempted the syntax below but I am getting an error of

> Method 'Rarnge' of object '_Worksheet' failed

What do I need to do differently in my code below to get the syntax to return the values I desire?

```
Dim destSheet As Worksheet: Set destSheet = Sheets("Main")

For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "O").Value) Then
        Sheets("Data").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$C").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
        Sheets("Main").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        form2 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-15],Lookup!C[-15]:C[-13],3,FALSE),"""")"
        destSheet.Range("P:P" & lr).Formula = form2
    Else
        Sheets("Data").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        Sheets("Main").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        form3 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-15],Lookup!C[-15]:C[-13],3,FALSE),"""")"
        destSheet.Range("P:P" & lr).Formula = form3
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bit hard to understand for me what you are trying to do, please correct me if I get you wrong.

First of all selecting sheets is not a preferred method while running macros, unless you intentionally do it, so avoid it.

Secondly, you don't need to filter anything, you can control it by checking conditions within your code. You don't do things physically, you do them theoretically within your code, and display the output.
Have a look at this code and ask wherever you need help to understand.

```
Sub VLookups()

Dim destSheet As Worksheet: Set destSheet = Sheets("Main")
Dim i As Long
Dim myVal As Variant

Set lookupRange = Sheets("Data").Range("$A:$C") 'This is your lookup range

For i = 2 To Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Iterate from 2nd row till last row
    myVal = Application.VLookup(destSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value, lookupRange, 2, False)
    If IsError(myVal) Then GoTo Skip 'If searched value not found then skip to next row

    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "O").Value) Then 'If Cell in Column O not empty
        If myVal = "YOUR X VALUE FOR COLUMN B" Then 'If Your Column B X value exists
            destSheet.Cells(i, "P").Value = Application.VLookup(destSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value, _
            lookupRange, 3, False) 'Column P Cell is populated by Data Sheet Column C Cell
        End If
    Else 'If Cell in Column O empty
        If myVal <> "YOUR X VALUE FOR COLUMN B" Then 'If Your Column B X value not exists
            destSheet.Cells(i, "P").Value = Application.VLookup(destSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value, _
            lookupRange, 3, False) 'Column P Cell is populated by Data Sheet Column C Cell
        End If
    End If
Skip:
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This will work if the value in column A is only included once.  It seems that if the value in Column A exists twice it will only lookup the 1st value?

Comment: vlookup finds the first value by nature. If you want nth result, it is a different question which you can start digging [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817557/vba-vlookup-multiple-results)